# How to sort DList?

Tags: list, sorting, d

How to sort DList and SList in-place?

In Python we can do list.sort(), in Java - Collections.sort(linkedList, new Comparator ...)

I can't figure out how to do the same in D.

Comment: The standard library's [reference](https://dlang.org/phobos/index.html) probably has an answer, most likely in `std.algorithm`. Alternatively, there's a search box over there.

Comment: @Michail, I found several solutions in the standard library, but not quite what I was looking for. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting a linked list is inefficient which is why [`sort`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_sorting.html#.sort) requires a random access range as input. You probably want to either use arrays with direct memory access:

```
import std.algorithm, std.container, std.stdio;
void main()
{
    auto list = DList!int(2, 1, 3);
    list[].array.sort.release.writeln; // or directly start with an array
}
```

[Open on run.dlang.io](https://run.dlang.io/is/M5iqjV).

Or use sth. intrinsically sorted like a Heap or RBTree:

```
import std.algorithm, std.container, std.stdio;
void main()
{
    auto list = DList!int(2, 1, 3);
    list[].redBlackTree[].writeln;
}
```

[Open on run.dlang.io](https://run.dlang.io/is/n2HNwA).

Comment: actually sorting a linked list can happen in O(n log n) with only O(1) extra space using a merge sort.

Comment: Sure, but Quicksort is a lot faster in practice and being able to iterate directly over the array drastically helps the performance due to e.g. better cache use.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to add a specialisation to sort() to use merge-sort for DList objects...